# How can I change the name of an unencrypted LUKS partition mounted as the root filesystem?

Tags: boot, luks, mdadm, initramfs, dm-crypt

When I installed Linux, the block-device-path of my root LUKS device was `/dev/md125` and the unencrypted partition was `/dev/mapper/md125_crypt`. I have since renamed the MD device to `/dev/md0`, and now I'd like to rename the LUKS partition to `/dev/mapper/md0_crypt`. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Replaced all references (in the various *tabs) of `md125_crypt`
2. Updated my initramfs
3. Updated grub2

However, when I reboot, my system doesn't make it to the point of asking for my decryption password; it says something about being "unable to find the root partition".

I've also tried adding a symlink (`/dev/mapper/md125_crypt -> ./md0_crypt`) but it doesn't seem to persist after a reboot.

**How can I rename my unencrypted LUKS partition such that I can successfully boot after doing so?**

Answer (score 0):

When updating your `initramfs`, the root partition is detected from the running system -- not from your new/renamed config values. Instead, use a live cd and `chroot` to set the new name.

1. Boot into another/similar system (live/rescue cd).
2. Do `cryptsetup open /dev/md0 md0_crypt` to indicate the new root name `md0_crypt`.
3. Mount `/dev/mapper/md0_crypt`, with the partition for `/boot` and `--bind` mounts for `/dev` `/proc` `/sys` inside.
4. Do `chroot` into the mounted `md0_crypt`.

   1. Edit `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab` with the new root name.
   2. Update your initramfs plus grub's kernel parameters.
   3. Double-check everything before closing the `chroot`
5. Reboot into the main system.

Tested the above steps on Ubuntu 22.04, but with [refind](/questions/tagged/refind) (instead if grub); in that case, also edit `refind_linux.conf` to set the new root name in the kernel parameters.

---

Running `dmsetup rename md125_crypt md0_crypt` to temporarily change the name in `/dev/mapper` also seems like a viable option. As-is it doesn't affect the root partition detection in `update-initramfs` like `chroot` does though.